# How to test code that uses an object and its methods?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am trying to unit-test the following code with `py.test`:

```
def get_service_data():    
    client = requests.session()
    # some task on the client object

    resp = client.get('https://apiendpoint.xxx.com/yyy/', params={...})
    temp_json = resp.json()

    result = []
    # lots of processing on temp_json
    return result
```

However, if I monkeypatch `requests.session()`, the mocked object will not have the `get()` method. If I patch `requests.session.get()`, then the test code will output another error message:

```
>       monkeypatch.setattr('requests.session.get', lambda: {})
E       Failed: object <function session at 0x1046e3500> has no attribute 'get'
```

How should I test the above code?

Comment: Your monkeypatch of `session` should return an object with a `get` method, *just like the original does*. In turn, the result of `get` should have a `json` method. The `session` function itself doesn't have a `get` method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, but how should I create such an object?

Comment: That's what [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) is for. Alternatively, you could just create your own class that implements the single required method, then `monkeypatch.setattr('requests.session', lambda: ThatClass())`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It seems that define a temp class for mocking is the only way to patch the object if I use py.test, right? Would you post your idea as an answer (maybe add some more details:P? I will accept.

Comment: I'm not writing it for you! There are many options for mocking in such a simple case, you just need to create objects that define the appropriate methods (if you don't know how, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).